# how to filter the host which is used by other users

Tags: linux, tcsh

I would like to check whether others are log in the host or not. I have following tcsh script . **I would like to filter the host which is used by other users.** **I am using tcsh**.

```
    host_list="/home/campus27/zwang10/bin/hostlist"
    HOSTS=`cat $host_list`
    cp /dev/null hostlist_available
    for line in $HOSTS
    do 
    ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1s $line true &>/dev/null
    RESULT=$?
    if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo $line
    echo $line >> hostlist_available
    fi
    done
```

The above script will write all available hostname into `hostlist_available`.

But some other people are log in the available hosts. I would like to delete those hosts (except me). My username is `zwang10`.

Comment: So... What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker. I revised it.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you sure you're using tcsh? Unless I'm missing something this sure looks like bash syntax (square brackets, `fi` instead of `endif`, `for` instead of `foreach`...)

Answer (score 1):

insert this between your then and fi above.  Pardon if my syntax isn't bang on

```
for USER in ssh -f $line "w" | tail -n+3 | awk '{print $1}'
do
  # if user is empty OR user is me then
  if [[ $USER =~ ^\s*$ ]] || [[ "$USER." == "zwang10." ]]; then
    echo $line
    echo $line >> hostlist_available
  else
    echo "$line occupied by $USER"
  fi
done
```

I think this is roughly what you wanted.

Comment: I still got error `./HOST_AVAI_1.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' ./HOST_AVAI_1.sh: line 19: ` fi'`

Comment: With bash I like to make little mockups of what I'm trying to do if only to isolate problem areas.  This example is tricky in that respect as I'm not sure what the output of your ssh commands yeild, I presume its a list of hosts, then a list of users.  Once each problem is solved the script can be condensed to it's full form.